# Get Last Row of "or" statement in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a statement sample like below;

```
SELECT * FROM abctable WHERE (_variableX >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND _variableY IS NULL) OR (_variableY > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

What I want to accomplish is, If I get multiple results from "or" statement which is `OR (_variableY > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);`, I just want to get the last row of it.

If I limit just the `OR` statement, I get an error and If I limit the whole statement then I will only have X result. I will have multiple result from both cases but I want to get **whole result** from `(_variableX >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND _variableY IS NULL)` and I only want to get the **last row** from `OR (_variableY > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);` statement.

How could I manage it in the simplest way?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit: I am sorry I forgot to mention that I want to get only the last element of every unique result from the second statement**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it all in one. However the result can be obtained using union:

```
( SELECT * FROM abctable WHERE (_variableX >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND _variableY IS NULL) )

UNION 

( SELECT  * FROM abctable WHERE (_variableY > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND _variableY in (SELECT max(_variableY) from abctable group by username)
```

)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am sorry I forgot to mention that I only want to get the last element of every unique element, could it be done with `DISTINCT` using `UNION` ?

Comment: You could try putting the DISTINCT as shown and it might work.

Comment: Can you please upload the actual tables from the database so that I can work with the fields easier

Comment: Also the last row will differ depending on what you order by therefore you need to order by a specific field DESC

Comment: Database with some samples [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a0263/1) (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a0263/1) it didnt let me add more samples. `_variableX` is `_accttime`, `_variableY` is `_acctsoptime`

Comment: If the result is Unique then there will only ever be one row of it

Comment: I want to get whole data with null `acctstoptime` (first statement) and get the most recent `acctstoptime` for each username. Is there any other way to accomplish this? by the way thank you for your helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126960/discussion-between-djacobsdev-and-lunatic-fnatic).